# Why did the time format in Steam chat change after I started using xinit?

Tags: locale, steam

The time format in my Steam chat used to look like this: `23:59`

After I stopped using Slim and started using xinit, it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

This only displays the hour and the time zone, which isn't useful. Since the format changed after I started using xinit, I'm assuming I have some control over how the time format looks in chat.

I want the format to go back to the 24 hour military time like it used to be. Does anybody know how?

I also heartily accept any pointers in the comments or chat.

---

My `LC_*` environment variables look like this:

```
$ env | grep LC
LC_PAPER=nb_NO.utf8
LC_MONETARY=nb_NO.utf8
LC_NUMERIC=nb_NO.utf8
LC_MEASUREMENT=nb_NO.utf8
LC_TIME=nb_NO.utf8
```

Typing `date` in the command line shows this output:

```
$ date
sø. 19. april 18:46:02 +0200 2015
```